# Remapping the Asus Transformer keyboard. How to insert acute accent?

Tags: keyboard, character, dock, diacritics, transformer-model

I am trying to change the keyboard dock layout to that of Icelandic standard keyboard using this guide : [xda developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1144204), however im having difficulties finding the acute accent ´ that is used to type á,ó,é,í,ý,ú in Icelandic.

Is there anyone out there that can help me with this problem?

Comment: Yes, I'd like the same ... for accents used in Italian. This seems like a large oversight by Asus; and one that should be easily fixed (e.g. by using Ctrl and/or Alt in combination with a character to pop up a menu of accents relevant to that character).